# Hessian of the action of a complex scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, variational-principle, action

Suppose, I wanted to compute the Hessian of the action of a complex scalar field with
$S[\phi,\phi^*]=\int \phi(-\Delta+m^2)\phi^{*}+V[\phi,\phi^*]$,
say the potential is $\sim (\phi\phi^{*})^2$.

For some reason I do not obtain the same result if I rewrite the field as $\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\phi_1+i\phi_2)$ and simply compute $\delta_{\phi_i}\delta_{\phi_j}S[\phi_1,\phi_2]$. Perhaps, I use the wrong (?) Hessian in the complex case? How should it look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have something like a coordinate transformation in the field space:

$$\pmatrix{\phi\\\phi^*}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{\phi_1+i\phi_2\\\phi_1-i\phi_2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1 & i\\ 1 & -i}\pmatrix{\phi_1\\\phi_2}$$

Which is a linear transformation of the form $\vec y = A \vec x$ or, in components, $y_i = A_{ij} x_j$

So the situation is similar to the question if $$H_{ij}=\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j}f(\vec x)$$ is the same as $$\bar H_{ij}=\partial_{y_i}\partial_{y_j}f(A^{-1}\vec y)$$

Obviously, it is not, since entries of $A$ will enter $\bar H_{ij}$.

Here is how a Hessian transforms under coordinate change: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359851/hessian-after-coordinate-changing